# Storing long quasiquote matchers in a variable

Tags: scala, string-interpolation, scala-quasiquotes

I'm trying to avoid repetition of long quasiquotes in matches. So, I'd like to convert this:

```scala
def appendTree(clazz: ClassDef, tree: Tree): ClassDef =
  clazz match {
    case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" =>
      q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats; ..$tree }"
  }
```

to something like this:

```scala
val clazzQuote = "$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }"

def appendTree(clazz: ClassDef, tree: Tree): ClassDef =
  clazz match {
    case q"$clazzQuote" =>
      q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats; ..$tree }"
  }
```

A comparable example of what I'm trying to do with string interpolation:

```scala
val msg = "hello $name"

"hello world" match {
  case s"$msg" => println(name) // I want this to output "world"
}
```

This example [doesn't work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FNONvdlLRWmkHwgQomzWsA) either.

How can I do this? (or can I?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write

```
val msg = s"hello $name" // name doesn't make sense here
```

or

```
val clazzQuote = "$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }"
// mods, tpname, tparams, ... do not make sense here
```

That's not how pattern matching work in Scala.

You can write either

```
clazz match {
  case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" =>
    q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats; $tree }"
}
```

or

```
clazz match {
  case ClassDef(mods, name, tparams, Template(parents, self, body)) =>
    ClassDef(mods, name, tparams, Template(parents, self, body :+ tree))
}
```

or

```
clazz match {
  case c: ClassDef =>
    val i = c.impl
    ClassDef(c.mods, c.name, c.tparams, Template(i.parents, i.self, i.body :+ tree))
}
```

If you need not all parameters you can use underscores

```
clazz match {
  case q"$_ class $tpname[..$_] $_(...$_) extends $_" =>
    println(tpname)
}
```

or

```
clazz match {
  case q"$_ class $_[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$parents { $_ => ..$_ }" =>
    println(parents)
}
```

In complex cases you can use custom extractor objects.

If you often add a tree to class body you can introduce helper method

```
def modifyBody(clazz: ClassDef, f: List[Tree] => List[Tree]): ClassDef =
  clazz match {
    case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" =>
      q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..${f(stats)} }"
  }

def appendTree(clazz: ClassDef, tree: Tree): ClassDef = {
  clazz match {
    case c => modifyBody(c, stats => stats :+ tree)
}
```

Comment: Hmm it looks like I'd better go without quasiquote on this one as it looks less cluttered without it. This is really a great answer. Thanks!