# MacroAnnotation to remove annotation from method's type member

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I'm learning how to write Scala Macros and wrote a macro annotation that removes an annotation from a type parameter of an annotated function. Here it is.

**The annotation to remove**:

```
class garbage extends StaticAnnotation
```

**Implementation of macro to remove the annotation**:

```
@compileTimeOnly("Compile-time only annotation")
class removeGarbage extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro impl
}

object removeGarbage {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*) = {
    import c.universe._
    println(annottees)
    val expandee = annottees.toList collect {
      case q"$mods def $templatename[..$typeparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body" =>
        val modifiedParams = typeparams collect {
          case q"$mods type $name[..$args] = $tpt" =>
            val modifiedMods = mods match {
              case Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots) =>
                Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots.filter(_ == q"new garbage()"))
            }
            q"$modifiedMods type $name[..$args] = $tpt"
        }
        q"$mods def $templatename[..$modifiedParams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body"
      case annottee =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$annottee cannot be annotated with @removeGarbage. Only def methods are allowed")
    }
    println(expandee)
    q"..$expandee"
  }
}
```

**Test method**:

```
trait Test{
  @removeGarbage
  def someMethod[@garbage Source, G[_]](i: Int): G[List[Int]]
}
```

---

That seem to work fine. To check it I compared the log added with `println(annottees)` and `println(expandees)`:

```
List(def someMethod[@new garbage() Source, G[_]](i: Int): G[List[Int]])
List(def someMethod[Source, G[_]](i: Int): G[List[Int]])
```

***The problem*** about the solution is it looks difficult to read. Maybe I didn't use quasiquotes to their full potential. Is there a way to simplify the macro implementation (probably using quasiquotes more extensively...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ok for a macro code to be difficult to read :)
This is why metaprogramming shouldn't be the tool #1.

I can't see how your code can be reduced significantly.

You can replace

```
val modifiedMods = mods match {
  case Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots) =>
    Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots.filter(_ == q"new garbage()"))
}
```

with one-liner

```
val modifiedMods = mods.mapAnnotations(_.filter(_ == q"new garbage()"))
```

If you keep doing the same set of transformations in many macros you can similarly define helper methods like `mapDef`, `mapTypeParams` ...

If quasiquotes become too cumbersome you [can consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840692/storing-long-quasiquote-matchers-in-a-variable) to use `ClassDef`, `Template`, `DefDef` ... instead of quasiquotes or mix them with quasiquotes when convenient.

(Such questions are normally for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ although metaprogramming seems to be [not](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-programming+scala) [so](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros+scala) popular there.)